# OpenGL shows nothing

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have a problem while trying to render a triangle with OpenGL using LWJGL.
It's doing nothing, it's neither render something nor does it throw any error.
glClear() is working (if I change the color, the color changes).

You can find a GLIntercept Log here:
[GLIntercept Log](http://pastebin.com/RJ7aySgg)

This is my OpenGL Initialization-Code:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(true);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);

glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600); // my display size
```

After that I bind my shaders:

```
int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader , vertexShaderCode);
glCompileShader(vertexShader );

int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader , fragmentShader Code);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

int program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vert");
glLinkProgram(program);
glDetachShader(program, vertexShader);
glDetachShader(program, fragmentShader);
```

This are the shaders:

colored.vert

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 camera;
uniform mat4 model;

uniform vec4 color;

in vec3 vert;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = camera * model * vec4(vert, 1);
    fragColor = color;
}
```

colored.frag

```
#version 150

in vec4 fragColor;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {
    finalColor = fragColor;
}
```

Then I create vbo, ibo and vao:

```
// VBO
FloatBuffer vboBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
vboBuffer.put(
    0, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    -1, 0, 0);
vboBuffer.flip();
vbo = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// IBO
ShortBuffer iboBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(3);
iboBuffer.put(0, 1, 2);
iboBuffer.flip();
ibo = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboBuffer,  GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// VAO
vao = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(program, "vert"));
glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(program, "vert"), 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * Float.SIZE, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I have changed that as advised by Andon M. Coleman to match the core profile:
It does not resolve my issue!

```
// IBO
ShortBuffer iboBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(3);
iboBuffer.put(0, 1, 2);
iboBuffer.flip();

// VBO
FloatBuffer vboBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
vboBuffer.put(
    0, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    -1, 0, 0);
vboBuffer.flip();

// VAO
vao = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vao);

ibo = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboBuffer,  GL_STATIC_DRAW);

vbo = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(program, "vert"));
glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(program, "vert"), 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * Float.SIZE, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Before rendering:

```
glUseProgram(program);
glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "color"), colorR, colorG, colorB, colorA);
glUseProgram(0);
```

Rendering:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(program);
FloatBuffer cameraBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
// a simple orthographic camera at the position (0|0|1)
// left: -1; right: 1; bottom: -1; top: 1; zNear: -1; zFar: 1
cameraBuffer.put(
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
cameraBuffer.flip();
glUniformMatrix4(glGetUniformLocation(program, "camera"), false, cameraBuffer);
FloatBuffer modelBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
// no translation applied, so its an identity matrix
modelBuffer .put(
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
modelBuffer.flip();
glUniformMatrix4(glGetUniformLocation(program, "model"), false, modelBuffer);

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glUseProgram(0);

// check for OpenGL errors
int error_code = glGetError();
if(error_code != GL_NO_ERROR)
    System.err.print("OpenGL Error: " + gluErrorString(error_code));
```

That are all OpenGL commands I do in the correct order.

GLIntercept Log:
[GLIntercept Log](http://pastebin.com/RJ7aySgg)

Comment: Why is `camera.m33` = **-1**, and why are you trying to apply translation in your projection matrix? There is a view matrix designed for that. You should start out with identity matrices and wind your vertices clockwise in NDC space, if that works then you can start modifying your projection / viewing transformation. You also changed the default front winding. There are a **lot** of potential causes of your problem here, start by using no face culling and removing the redundant `glDepthRange (...)` call.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! What is wrong with the projection matrix? Using zNear=-1 & zFar=1 the value -1 sounds reasonable for me (-1/(far-near)). The cameraMatrix is in fact a projection matrix and a view matrix that are combined before. But I will follow your debugging advices to get my code finally working... hopefully..

Comment: It is just that using **-1** there will reverse your winding direction. And you have face culling enabled. You have your NDC vertices wound clockwise right now, but flipping the Z axis in the projection matrix makes them counter-clockwise, which will be culled using your current state setup.

Comment: That makes sense... I just edited my code to give only two identity matrices to the shaders, as well as removing face culling... nothing changed. Still black screen :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is resolved.
The problem was that `glVertexAttribPointer()` expects the stride to be in bytes, while `Float.SIZE` in Java returns the size in bits.

Wrong:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(..., ..., ..., ..., 3 * Float.SIZE, ...);
```

Right:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(..., ..., ..., ..., 3 * Float.SIZE / 8, ...);
```